Sell Logic When Using Triple Barrier method for Buy Signals Only
I have defined a rules based primary indicator that does a decent job predicting future uptrends. For better results, I want to take all records where the primary indicator occurs and feed it through a classifier using the triple barrier method as labels. Initial results are showing that this classifier is able to reduce the number of bad buys by a significant percentage.
This is great but I am having trouble with the sell logic. My basic sell logic uses the barriers from labeling to set profit and stop loss limits. If no limit is hit I sell at the vertical barrier.
This does not work very well so far. Curious if others have any recommendations. Should I be using a moving stop loss and just let it ride? I feel like I may be missing something obvious.
